# How can I interrupt the following result

Tags: openssl

I ran openssl speed on my windows computer. Here are Some results:

Doing aes-256 cbc for 3s on 16384 size blocks: 22339 aes-256 cbc's in 3.00s

Then later on I found this result as well

The 'numbers' are in 1000s of bytes per second processed.

aes-256 cbc     101857.81k   118932.14k   123299.19k   126217.56k   125313.02k   122000.73k

I have a string of 344 byte. How can I find the time used to encrypt and decrypt the string using AES based on the pervious result from openssl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about feeding in "344" byte buffers as fast as you can, then you will be somewhere between 256 byte result and 1024 byte result, most likely nearing the 256 byte result, so > 123288.1K bytes per second and < 126217.56K bytes per seconds.

If you are talking about how old to encrypt or decrypt ONE 344 byte string?  It doesn't... you can take your:
Doing aes-256 cbc for 3s on 256  size blocks: x aes-256 cbc's in ys.

And work out how long it took to do a 1 256 byte block time on average by dividing y / x and that will have you an average for a 256 byte buffer.  You will be close to that on average.  I'm guessing a pretty small fraction of a second judging by the bytes per second value.